# How to handle Copyright notice in javascript bundle?

Tags: typescript, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs, copyright-display

I was writing a couple of small demos to explain decorators (in typescript) to colleagues when I noticed that my bundle had a Microsoft Copyright notice that kind of make my entire file free for all (and made by MS).

How should this be handled effectivly (if I create something that isn't free)?

I used Typescript 3.1 to compile and rollup for bundling.

code:

```js
import { isNotUndefined, isNotNullOrUndefined } from "goodcore/Test";

function deprecated<S>(instead?: string, message?: string) {
    // Logic removed for brevity...
}

class Car {
    @deprecated()
    public turnIgnitionKey() {
        this.start();
    }
    public pressStartButton() {
        this.start();
    }
    private start() {
        console.log("Running!");
    }
}

let car = new Car();
car.turnIgnitionKey();
car.pressStartButton();
```

and bundle beginning (where the last function is mine and those before are MS):

```
'use strict';

/*! *****************************************************************************
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use
this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the
License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

THIS CODE IS PROVIDED ON AN *AS IS* BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, EITHER EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION ANY IMPLIED
WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF TITLE, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE,
MERCHANTABLITY OR NON-INFRINGEMENT.

See the Apache Version 2.0 License for specific language governing permissions
and limitations under the License.
***************************************************************************** */

function __decorate(decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
}

function __metadata(metadataKey, metadataValue) {
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.metadata === "function") return Reflect.metadata(metadataKey, metadataValue);
}

function isNullOrUndefined(arg) {
    return arg === undefined || arg === null;
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I added rollup-plugin-terser in my rollup config and set comments to false so all comments are removed.

```
...
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
...
plugins: [
    ...
    terser({ format: { comments: false } }),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Rollup bundles everything that is needed into output files. What you see there are Typescript helpers from `tslib` module.

You can replace that code (and get rid of MS license) with `tslib` library imports.

Add to your `rollup.config.js` following setting: `external: ["tslib"]`. Unfortunatelly you need to add `tslib` module to your dependencies (or peerDependencies) to your project.

check following conversations for more details:
https://github.com/ezolenko/rollup-plugin-typescript2/issues/58 (about external setting)

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2436#issuecomment-371585945 (about issues with dependency vs peerDependency)

and here about helpers:
https://mariusschulz.com/blog/external-helpers-library-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

@JGoodgive,

You could potentially add your own custom license above every JavaScript file you create so when its bundled up together, your license file should show above your JS code.

```
/*! *****************************************************************************
Copyright (c) <Author>. All rights reserved.
<Custom license text here>
***************************************************************************** */

// Your JS code below your custom license
```

Comment: This not works here, something alternative to `external: ["tslib"]`?